Calculating closest point referenced to centroid in QGIS
I have a QGIS project in which I work with a polygon layer ('POLIGONS_TEST') and a point layer ('PUNTS_TEST').
I use the following Geometry Generator expression on the 'POLIGONS_TEST' layer to draw a line that joins the centroid of each polygon with the nearest points layer 'PUNTS_TEST'.
make_line(
    centroid($geometry), 
    closest_point(
        overlay_nearest('PUNTS_TEST', $geometry,limit:=1)[0],
        $geometry
        )
    )


As you can see in the screenshot, the result is correct but there is but there is a visual inconsistency. The closest_point function returns the closest point from geometry1 to geometry2. It seems that it considers geometry1 as the polygon's boundary and not as the centroid.
How could I solve this so that the proximity is calculated concerning the centroid, without having to convert the polygon layer to a point layer?
Example:

Unsatisfactory result after applying the expression proposed by the users @Erik and @Andrea:


Not sure to understand... "the result is correct" or not? What is the meaning of the blu lines in the second screenshot?

The blue lines seem to be the expected results.

In the second screenshot there is also a grey line non flagged by a red X (which I suppose mark the unexpected results). What it means? Is it also an expected result?

I clarify this sentence. The result is correct with respect to the properties of the closest_point geometry function. What I am looking for is some solution to consider the centroid as the reference point and not the boundary.
Regarding the screenshot, the gray lines are the result of the expression. The red lines is an indicator to say that it is not the expected result. And the blue lines are the expected result.

In the second screenshot there is also a grey line (maybe, two) not flagged by a red X. Is it an expected result or not? How do you check a point is closest to a centroid or not?
Please provide the layers.

Andrea, I add a screenshot marking with a red cross the lines of your expression with unsatisfactory results.
The result I would like to obtain I add them manually in green color. I calculate these lines manually with the line measuring tool. I add the distance value

Please, do not forget about "What should I do when someone answers my question?"

You are conducting your overlay check on the polygons, not their centroids. Try changing the expression to
make_line(centroid($geometry), 
    closest_point(overlay_nearest('PUNTS_TEST',
    centroid($geometry),limit:=1)[0],
    $geometry)
)


Erik, the result I get with the expression you propose is the same I get with my expression. I have to discard your solution. I am sorry.

The expression inside the overlay_nearest function is "an optional expression to evaluate on the features from the target layer". So the centroid function inside the other answers is evaluated on the point ('PUNTS_TEST') layer, not the polygon ('POLIGONS_TEST') layer, which is why it has no effect.
In this case you can avoid using the overlay_nearest function altogether by:

creating a variable (@centroid) to hold the centroid
using the aggregate function to create an array of points from the PUNTS_TEST layer
use the collect_geometries function to turn that into a multipoint geometry
find the closest point (closest_point) from the multipoint to the @centroid
finally making the line from that point to the @centroid using make_line

with_variable('centroid',centroid(@geometry),
    make_line(
        closest_point(
            collect_geometries(
                aggregate('PUNTS_TEST',
                aggregate:='array_agg',
                expression:=@geometry)
            )
        ,@centroid)
    ,@centroid)
)


